# How would you use a function to calculate current and voltage across array of resistors?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{

    int res[10];
    double vol[10];
    int i;
    int n;


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter R and V for resistor %d: ", i+1);
        n = scanf("%d %lf", res[i], vol[i]);
    }
```

How would you write a function which uses the resistor and voltage values entered by the user repeatedly, which are stored in an array.

Then from the main function, an function outside of main is called to calculate CURRENT AND VOLTAGE across each resistor element from an array.

i tried this function..

```
int rv (int i, int *res, double *vol) {

int count = 0;
int n;
while (count < 10) {

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cur[i] = (vol[i]/res[i]);
    return cur[i]
    }
    count++;
 }
```

Comment: How do you know which resistors are in parallel and which are in series?

Comment: we don't need to know parallel and series we're just using the voltage and resistor value entered by the user to calculate current and power using the basic ohms law formulas...I = V/R and Power = V * I

Comment: Just a sidenote: the scanf() call is wrong. You have to pass pointers, not values to that function: scanf("...", &res[i], &vol[i])

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not changing in your 2nd loop.  Why not use another `for` loop instead?

Comment: and now you are double-looping -- or you would be, if there wasn't a return in the middle of the loop body.  The inner loop, with a return after, should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to your code you alreay have the voltage.

To find the current you'll need to use [ohms law](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_2/1.html).

> R(ohms) = V(volts)/A(amps)

---

**In Response to your Sample Function**

Decide whether you are calling it once per resistor, or once for the array.

If it is per array then the arguments need changing.

IF it is per item then you need change the function code.

Comment: just like in the function above...and how would i store those values to do other operations...

Comment: you do have 2 errors in your function code. I can not see where `double *cur` is declared and you are returning in your `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

- Variables defined inside of a function, only "live" for the duration of that function. In general, any time a variable is defined, it ends at the `}` that matches the `{` before its definition. So, your `count` variable is a new counter every time you call `rv`, set to `0`. But that is probably more-or-less what you wanted to do, except…
- Once you `return`, your function exits. You are `return`ing the value of `cur[0]`, but never getting a chance to continue through to the other resistors.

Here's a few ideas:

- Have a function to compute the R value (resistance?) of a single resistor.
- Create a loop that calls that function repeatedly and finds the (sum?) of them.

Here's some partial code you might like to emulate and flesh out :-)

```
 double resistance_of (int res, double vol) {
    return res / vol;
 }

 /* I dunno the math you would actually want to do. */
 double average_of_resistance (int num_resistors, int* res, double* vol) {
    int i = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    while (i < num_resistors) { /* could also use for(;;) here */
         sum = sum + resistance_of (res[i], vol[i]);
         ++i;
    }
    return sum / num_resistors;
 }

 int main (int param_count, char** param) {
    int how_many = 0;
    int res[20];
    double vol[20];
    while (how_many < 1 || how_many > 20) { 
        printf ("\nHow many resistors? ");
        scanf ("%d", how_many);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many; ++i) {
        printf("\nenter R and V for resistor # %d: ", i);
        scanf ("%d %lf", res[i], vol[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n OK, the average is %f", average_of (how_many, res, vol));
    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: average is one of the thing i need to do later..thanks but this is also what i'm trying to do:

Your program should repeatedly prompt the user to enter resistance and voltage values for each resistor, concluding when one of two conditions is met:
• The user enters Ctrl-Z (and then Enter) to indicate the end of the list
• user enters a total of 10 resistors (the maximum allowed number).

Comment: Well, for trapping ^Z, you're going to need something more complex than `scanf` in that loop.  I didn't notice the *homework* tag, I'm afraid I've probably gone a bit over the top with this example, but check your manuals on loops, variable scopes and `return`, at the very least. It would seem you've a few fundamental elements that you'll want to work out your understanding of.